# Akeneo demo instance authentication 403 forbidden

Tags: authentication, postman, akeneo

I'm trying to use the demo instance that Akeneo provides, https://demo.akeneo.com, to test the rest API, but I can't get past the authentication process.

I've been following the documentation, at https://api.akeneo.com/api-reference.html#post_token, but the responses from the requests are all the same.

This is what I've been doing until now:

Request:

`

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://demo.akeneo.com/api/oauth/v1/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic NV80YXNxZGhqbjk3aThjb2s4MDRva29jMGd3ODQwNG93c293Y3NjODhnY3c0czA4d2NzMDo1MzVybGZkN3FqNHNvd2MwdzBrb2NzODBjNDhzNDBnazR3Z2M4NDhvczRrZ2Nzb3d3aw==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "asdasdas_3080",
    "password": "2a3f76557",
    "grant_type": "password"
}'
```

`

Response:

`

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
    <center>
        <h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx</center>
</body>

</html>
```

`

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you correctly encoded your "Authorisation" ? You have to do something like this :  `base64("clientId" + ':' + "secret")`

Comment: @Pierre 100%. I'm trying to migrate an app that I developed for Akeneo version 2 or 3 which had the same authentication process. I've also downloaded the postman collection that Akeneo offers for the current version and which automatically encodes the authorization header which offered the same result.

Comment: I just tried and everything works perfectly for me with postman and the demo environment of Akeneo PIM.